# Functional and non-functional test

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing

I want to test the project I am working on before it publish it. I have done sytem test but I also want it to be tested by a focus group. My question is, is there a free available tool for testing my web app (.NET with MVC framework) so that stakeholders can test the system online before it got published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mainly 3 option,XUnit is the fav one:

**NUnit**

NUnit has the distinction of interoperating nicely with other tools, such as non-Microsoft build platforms and custom test runners.  On top of that, NUnit also has a reputation for fast testing running, and it has some nice additional features as well, including test annotations allowing easy specification of multiple inputs to a given test.

The main downside here is that it doesn’t integrate into Visual Studio the way that MSTest does.  Using it means doing extra work, and installing extra tools, regardless of how easy those tools’ authors may make the process.
XUnit

**MSTest**

MSTest ships with Visual Studio, so you have it right out of the box, in your IDE, without doing anything.  This lack of friction to getting started is arguably its killer feature.  The preferred .NET pattern for unit tests is to have a test project for each production (regular) project in your codebase.  With MSTest, getting that setup is as easy as File->New Project.  Then, when you write a test, you can right click on it and execute, having your result displayed in the IDE.  Pretty neat, huh?  And you can also see code coverage without installing any other tools.

On the con side, one of the most frequent knocks on MSTest is that of performance.  People find the experience can be sluggish.  On top of that, many people struggle with interoperability.  After all, Microsoft makes it so you can integrate with other Microsoft/Visual Studio stuff, so making it work with third party things would probably not rate as a priority.

**XUnit**

xUnit earns points for creating extremely intuitive terminology and ways to reason about the language of tests.  On top of that, the tool has a reputation for excellent extensibility.  Another awesome feature of xUnit is actually not a feature of the software, but a feature of the authors.  They have a reputation for commitment, responsiveness, and evangelism.

On the con side, some users seem to wish the tool had more documentation.  Beyond that, the community seems pretty enthusiastic and it’s hard to find a lot of detractors.  This may speak to an implicit con, however.  It has a small but loyal core of users because it requires a different way of thinking about some things and perhaps a bit more learning.

**Also tale a look at this:** [Why xUnit and not NUnit or MSTest](https://dev.to/hatsrumandcode/net-core-2-why-xunit-and-not-nunit-or-mstest--aei)

And this article is related to your request:
[Full system testing asp .Net mvc](https://livebook.manning.com/book/asp-net-mvc-4-in-action/chapter-20/1)

[Source](https://stackify.com/unit-test-frameworks-csharp/)